# A Better Way To Render Complicated Flash Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some complex message to show inside of a flash message so instead of having a long string in the controller, I extracted it to a partial. I do this:

```
flash[:success] = render(:partial => "complicated_message")
…
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

and then a normal view should be rendered which display the flash. This is a double render error, of course, since I have "wasted" a render on the partial.

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: do you mind sharing the whole action?

Comment: Use `render_to_string` instead. But remember that flash is stored in user's cookie. So don't put anything large there!

Comment: @Vezu There isn't any else of interest happening in there

Comment: @jdoe That's the way! Never saw that method before, but that's what I needed.

Comment: Cool. i learnt something today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as suggested by @jdoe is to use the render_to_string method instead.